# Create New Application of Yii Framework on cPanel

Tags: yii, cpanel

I uploaded Yii Framework to my cpanel and now I dont know how to create new application while I did it on my local host using CMD.

I have not any shell access on cpanel and search this question but I found no related answer for this question.

Please help me out!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to deploy your application in another way, eg. with FTP, git or rsync.

Upload your complete application, but make sure to exclude and/or set the correct permissions manually for certain folders eg. `assets` and `protected/runtime`.

Answer (score 0):

create your app on a local pc, then upload your app to your host. It's that simple.

you can skip making app using cmd on your host!

then just point to the frameworks location in index.php

Answer (score 0):

if you have other apps which are been used by your YII app make sure to install them from Cpanel install php packages.For instance if your using LDAP authentication run a php5-ldap package. If your not using any packages upload your site and your good to go.